# session.serialize_handler as igbinary causing "igbinary_unserialize_header: unsupported version"

Tags: linux, nginx, php

I have installed igbinary 1.1.1 from PECL, configured it as serializer for session.serialize_handler in php.ini so that it is shown in phpinfo(). The change was tested - so far everything is fine, but on live server, I can see warnings like this (was working without any problems with native php serializer):

```
PHP Warning: igbinary_unserialize_header: unsupported version: 1346458177, should be 1 or 2 in dispatcher.php on line 73
PHP Warning: session_start(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in dispatcher.php on line 73
PHP Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in dispatcher.php on line 73
```

These messages appear not all the time - session_start() from line 73 worked for me during tests and I can see also ~ %80 of successful requests in access log.

*Line 73:*

```
session_start();
```

What would be the solution?

PS I have Nginx 1.2.3, php5-fpm 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Comment: You want us to debug your code but you didn't even show it to us?! And this is Server Fault anyway, maybe you meant to post on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Relax. I don't need us to debug my code. There's just session_start() and the problem is caused by igbinary. My code is well tested and working with php serializer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the cursory Google examination I did, I suggest the following.

Half the results I found for `igbinary_unserialize_header: unsupported version` says that upgrading to the latest version in the repository worked, leading me to believe this is an unidentified bug.

The other half identified data being unserialized that was either not originally serialized by igbinary or corrupt. Not being originally serialized by igbinary sounds plausible here because you didn't run in to this problem in test, but you are in production. **Is it possible you are trying to unserialize sessions that your users started before you switched to igbinary?**

My suggestion for the next debugging step is to add some error handling somewhere to write the serialized strings that cause this error to a file somewhere. You can then test unserializing them yourself to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I got it! I will test it on local or staging... I need to start session with older config and then I switch to igbinary... Good idea. I will do it after the week-end. I will update the post after that. Happy New Years Eve!